# get joint probability from pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, probability

I have the following dataframe

```
{'state': {7192: 'healthy',
  7193: 'healthy',
  7194: 'healthy',
  7195: 'Non healthy',
  7196: 'Non healthy'},
 'type': {7192: 'W', 7193: 'A', 7194: 'W', 7195: 'W', 7196: 'A'}}
```

I would like to have the joint probability associated with this df.

P(State = healthy, type = A), P(State = healthy, type = W)  
P(State = Non healthy, type = A), P(State = Non healthy, type = W)

I tried with the groupby method but it didn't work. What is the most efficient way to do it.

EDIT : To clarify a little bit I want to count the occurrence of every couple (State, Type). In the example above this should be
P(State = healthy, type = A) = 1/5 , P(State = healthy, type = W) = 2/5
P(State = Non healthy, type = A) = 1/5, P(State = Non healthy, type = W) = 1/5

Thank you,

Comment: Can you elaborate on the joint probability? What exactly you want to do?

Comment: You can use [prob140](https://pythonhosted.org/prob140/tutorial.html) to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you can use `DataFrame.value_counts(normalize=True)` to achieve what you want. Note that `DataFrame.value_counts` is new to `pandas` >= 1.1.0. If you're using an older version you can achieve the same result with a different method.

First transform your dictionary to a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Pandas version >= 1.1.0

```
probs = df.value_counts(["state", "type"], normalize=True)

print(probs)
healthy      W       0.4
             A       0.2
Non healthy  W       0.2
             A       0.2

# Select individual probabilitiy:
healthy_a_prob = probs[("healthy", "A")]

print(healthy_a_prob)
0.2
```

If your pandas is older than 1.1.0 replace the first line in the above example with:

```
probs = df.groupby("state")["type"].value_counts() / len(df)

# rest is the exact same
```

If you want a cross-tabulated probability table, I would recommend using `pd.crosstab` with `normalize=True`:

```
crosstab_ptable = pd.crosstab(df["state"], df["type"], normalize=True)

print(crosstab_ptable)
type           A    W
state
Non healthy  0.2  0.2
healthy      0.2  0.4
```

If you're interested in marginal probabilities as well, you can use the `margins` argument:

```
crosstab_ptable = pd.crosstab(df["state"], df["type"], margins=True, normalize=True)

print(crosstab_ptable)
type           A    W  All
state
Non healthy  0.2  0.2  0.4
healthy      0.2  0.4  0.6
All          0.4  0.6  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much had an old version of pandas !

Comment: Awesome! If this worked for you, would you mind selecting this answer as correct so other users who have the same/similar question can quickly find a solution?